# Uploading PDF file can not find the file type

Tags: javascript, php, file-upload

I have done the coding for uploading files mainly PDF, it works with most 1 page files but doesn't seem to work with bigger documents PDFs or excel files. When you upload the files and it comes up with the error it show print "Error Code : ".$_FILES['pdfFile']['type']."
"; as blank and no file type.

I hope someone can help me with this.

Thanks
Steven

```html
if ( isset( $_FILES['pdfFile'] ) ) {
$allowedExts = array("gif", "pdf", "GIF", "jpeg", "JPEG", "jpg", "JPG", "png", "PNG", "xlsx");
$extension = strtolower(end(explode(".", $_FILES["pdfFile"]["name"])));

if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
     || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/pdf")
     || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/xlsx")
     || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
     || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
     || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
     || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
     || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
    && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 90000000000) // increased allowed size may be your problem
    && in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
{
   $source_file = $_FILES['pdfFile']['tmp_name'];
  $dest_file = "Files/emails/".$_FILES['pdfFile']['name'];
  $filetype = $_FILES['pdfFile']['type'];

  if (file_exists($dest_file)) {
   print "<p>The file name already exists!!</p>";
  }
  else {
   move_uploaded_file( $source_file, $dest_file )
   or die ("Error!!");
   if($_FILES['pdfFile']['error'] == 0) {
    print "<p>Pdf file uploaded successfully!</p>";
    print "<p><b><u>Details : </u></b></p>";
    print "<p>File Name : ".$_FILES['pdfFile']['name']."</p>";
    print "<p>File Size : ".$_FILES['pdfFile']['size']." bytes"."</p>";
    print "<p>File location : Files/emails/".$_FILES['pdfFile']['name']."</p>";
   }
  }
 }
 else {
  if ( $_FILES['pdfFile']['type'] != "application/pdf") {
   print "Error occured while uploading file : ".$_FILES['pdfFile']['name']."<br/>";
   print "Invalid  file extension, should be pdf !!"."<br/>";
   print "Error Code : ".$_FILES['pdfFile']['error']."<br/>";
   print "Error Code : ".$_FILES['pdfFile']['type']."<br/>";
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Check what the `error` entry contains first of all! If this is a matter of the file size, then likely you have no type, because your upload was rejected _completely_.

Comment: @CBroe its an error on the file type. Not sure why but it's not showing up that its a PDF when uploading

Comment: _“its an error on the file type”_ - what do you mean by that? PHP does not _have_ any error code relating to the “type” of a file upload to begin with. Did you or did you not check what `$_FILES['pdfFile']['error']` contains?

Comment: Just do a `var_dump($_FILES['pdfFile']);`, instead of _guessing_ … You will either see what error occurred, or what the _actual_ content of `type` is.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks for your quick reply.
When I upload the PDF:
 $_FILES['pdfFile']['error'] comes up with error code: 2

Comment: $_FILES['pdfFile']['type'] comes up with blank where with other files or PDFs it says: application/pdf

Comment: var_dump($_FILES['pdfFile']) says: array(5) { ["name"]=> string(55) "M2022-19 Minutes of STA General Meeting 07 Nov 2019.pdf" ["type"]=> string(0) "" ["tmp_name"]=> string(0) "" ["error"]=> int(2) ["size"]=> int(0) } Error Code :

Comment: So it _is_ an issue with the file size.

Comment: Oh right thanks sorry. How can I do it to upload bigger files as this is only 633kg?

Comment: Please go _research_ that, is has been discussed countless times before already. Or have an actual look into the documentation, https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.common-pitfalls.php

Comment: ok done all this and changed all the file size but thanks. just annoying